# Spring Data For MongoDB - Error in Aggregation for gt, gte, lt, lte operators

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a project which uses Spring Data to connect to a MongoDB database (version 1.8.0), currently I am trying to create an Aggregation query but its failing when I use any of the following operators: gt, gte, lt,lte

My aggregation query looks like this:

```
TypedAggregation<Rawdata> aggregation = newAggregation(Rawdata.class,
    match(Criteria.where("value").gte(value)),
    group("genotypeName","genotypeId","value"),
    sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "value"),
    limit(total)
);
AggregationResults<Rawdata> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Rawdata.class);
```

When I run it, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org/springframework/beans/PropertyMatches
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1287)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I am sure the problem is in the `gte`operator because if I replace it for `is`, my query runs with no issues.

I debugged up to `org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer` and it seems like Spring is trying to search inside my Rawdata class a field named `$gte` to determinate its type.

Any help will be very appreciated.

**EDIT:** As I mentioned, Spring seems to be looking for a property named `$gte` in my Rawdata class, after adding this property my aggregation query works.

So far my code is working but it looks to me like something is wrong.

Comment: Using the Gosling release of Spring Data MongoDB requires at least spring `4.1.7` or better. Would you mind checking your classpath for conflicting versions.

Comment: Hi Christoph, I checked my dependencies and any reference to Spring is using version 4.1.7, in fact I only added spring-data-mongodb:1.8.0 in my build.gradle file and it included any additional Spring package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tracking the error I identified Spring was looking inside my DTO a property named `$gte`(it will also look for `$ge`, `$lt`, `$lte`). After adding field for these properties and created its getter and setter methods my aggregation query operation is working.

I don't know if there is something wrong with my implementation of Spring Data for MongoDB or there is something wrong in version 1.8.0 of the API, but so far this has been the best possible solution.